# Prove that for some size of circuit there exists function which requires some number of gates

Tags: computational-complexity

> Prove that for every function $s(n)$ such that
>   $n≤s(n)≤\frac{2^n}{100n}$ there exists a Boolean function
>   $f:{0,1}^n→{0,1}$ such that $f$ doesn't have a Boolean circuit of size
>   $s(n)$ that computes it but has a Boolean circuit of size $10s(n)$

Could anyone give me some help ?

Comment: Since this is clearly homework, what have you tried?

Comment: @mjqxxxx I will come back to subject of complexity theory in next month.  Then I will edit and show my thoughts.  Similary I will analyse your reduction in one of my thread in next month. You are welcome in my threads with tag complexity-theory :) (Of course in next month there are new threads :)).  Thanks!